# Show / Hide a div with select options in Vue

Tags: vue.js, select

I wanted to know if there is a way to show or hide `<divs>` with `v-if` or `v-show`.

I have two options that I can choose:

```
<select class="form-select" v-model="chooseOption">
            <option value="Option1">Show Option1</option>
            <option value="Option2">Show Option2</option>
</select>
```

I also have two `<divs>` that I want to be shown when I choose the respective option:

```
<div v-if="chooseOption === 'Option1'">
    <a>This is Option1</a>
</div>

<div v-if="chooseOption === 'Option2'">
    <a>This is Option2</a>
</div>
```

But this does not seem to work.
Does anyone have a suggestion on how I could solve this?

Comment: How does the rest of your code look? Works fine for me

Comment: Well .. I forgot a comma in data, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Check this codesanbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-phoebe-yvljkl?file=/src/components/Example.vue

Are you defining the data function of your component correctly?

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      chooseOption: null,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're here, make sure you check that the type of the value of the key in your data are the same.

If you're using a Boolean value in your data and the value of your options are `true` or `false` strings, you may have a problem. Change the value of your data to be a string too.

```
// your select options
<option value="true">True</option>
<option value="false">False</option>


// your div. You can also use v-show
<div v-if="show"></div>

data(){
  return {
   show: 'false', // instead of true
  }
}
```